# Не привязываются события мыши в QWebEngineView в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qwebengineview, eventfilter

Использую `QWebEngineView` в *PyQt5*. Никак не удается привязать события мыши (движения и события типа `on_click`) на открытой `web` странице.

Вот такие попытки успехов не приносят. Что я не так делаю?

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, QUrl

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MouseFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        print(obj, event)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class Web(QWebEngineView):
    def load(self, url):
        self.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, False)


class Root(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, flags=Qt.Widget)
        self.stack_widget = QStackedWidget(self)

        box = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        web_browser = Web()
        web_browser.load("url")
        mouse_filter = MouseFilter()
        web_browser.installEventFilter(mouse_filter)

        self.stack_widget.addWidget(web_browser)
        box.addWidget(self.stack_widget)
        self.setLayout(box)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Root()
    form.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QBoxLayout, QStackedWidget, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QUrl, QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings


#class MouseFilter(QObject):
#    @pyqtSlot()
#    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
#        print(obj, event)
#        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class Web(QWebEngineView):
    def load(self, url):
        self.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, False)


class Root(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, flags=Qt.Widget)
        self.stack_widget = QStackedWidget(self)

        box = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        web_browser = Web()
        web_browser.load("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024513/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%b2-qwebengineview-%d0%b2-pyqt5") #("url")

#        mouse_filter = MouseFilter()
#        web_browser.installEventFilter(mouse_filter)
        web_browser.installEventFilter(self)                      # +++

        self.stack_widget.addWidget(web_browser)

        box.addWidget(self.stack_widget)
        self.setLayout(box)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):                            # +++
        print("\n{}\n{}".format(obj.title() , event))
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Root()
    form.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, движения мыши отслеживаются и, я так понимаю, что события типа `on_touch\on_click` нужно реализовывать иным способом?